# JDBC Resultsets are stored in?

Tags: jdbc, resultset, heap-memory, sap-ase

I know this may be a lame and silly question but i'm unable to figure out the internal working  strategy for the JDBC resultset and am unable to find a way to figure it out myself by running   some samples.. well the question is where are the resultsets actually stored? Is it in the JVM's heap space or the database temp location.

Say for instance I have a table with 1000 rows and when I do a query to fetch the resultset with the fetch size as 20 (or with a default size set by vendor imp.) , then where are these 20 rows stored? I know that jdbc doesn't pick up all the 1000 rows at a time and keep it in memory but works only with the a few rows at a time..

Database : Sybase Ase
JDBC version : JDBC 3 /JDBC 4 (uing jconn jars)

Please let me know as i'm unable to get the answer to this exact query, or if you can direct me to the right material I will have a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the driver implementation, but usually in heap.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel , ok so normally when I try to query, the jdbc connection is made with the db, and the first x records are pulled in from DB and stored in the heap space and the processing is done. And when the cursor has no more rows in the heap mem, then a DB call is again made? OR the complete results are already available in the  JDBC driver and just the records are transformed to the client side for processing? Hope I made the question clear, if not please let know!

Comment: Simply put, where are the complete DB query sets saved for the result set to process..

Comment: 1) JDBC (type 4) is client side, 2) details depend on the implementation of the driver *and* the database. However roughly, the driver asks X records from the db and stores those in heap. When it needs more, it asks for more. If the db has all rows already materialized, or produces them on demand depends on multiple factors which are highly db, query etc dependent.

Comment: Thanks, so roughyly for every X records a DB call is made. And the query which we are dealing with here is just a "select * from table" without any limit or offset.. And could you please let me know which scenario suits the "If the db has all rows already materialized" condition? And when you say it asks for more, does it again query the select * stuff? or is there a temp internal db memory where all the results from the above query are stored and when rs.next is invoked, it just gets the data from the temp db memmory?

Comment: does my question makes sense? anyone?